# Function won't fully execute when called from another file Swift / Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a BLE app and as I'm going around codes and examples I found the best practices would be to keep all BLE functionality in its own .swift file and just access it from the view controllers, so far this is working fine, however I am having issues with a very specific thing:
I have a tabbed application that has a disabled tab (unless it's connected to a device). The purpose is that this menu or set of items should only be enabled once you pair up with the device, so I made a method in my MainViewController.swift as follows:

```
func enableDeviceTab()
{
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = "!"
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].isEnabled = true
    print("Enabling  Device Tab")
}
```

This works fine if I run it from within the MainViewController, However if I go to my BLEManager.swift file I'm trying to run in the following way, which I am not sure its the most appropriate (I do actually get the print message, however the tab is not enabled):

```
  var mainVC = MainViewController()

  class BLEManager {
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var bLEHandler : BLEHandler // this will be the delegate


    init() {
        self.bLEHandler = BLEHandler()
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self.bLEHandler, queue: nil)
    }
}

class BLEHandler : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
// CODE THAT WORKS
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to device!")
        displayStatusAlert(localmsg: "Connection Successful!")
        mainVC.enableDeviceTab()
    }
```

NOTE: I did not copy-paste the whole thing so there might be a bracket or two missing, disregard that, the only relevant lines (I think) are the following:

var mainVC = MainViewController()
and
mainVC.enableDeviceTab()

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the difference between a file or class and an instance of a type defined in that file. `var mainVC = MainViewController()` is creating a new `MainViewController` which is completely independent from the one whose view you see as part of your tab bar controller. You are therefore calling `enableDeviceTab` on a controller which has a nil `tabBarController`.

In cases like this it is not enough to know the *type* you want to communicate with. You need a *reference* to the specific instance of that type you want to modify or invoke behavior on.

Comment: For what it's worth this may be the single most common iOS question I see here. It gets asked in all kinds of ways usually something like "how do I pass a value to another view controller". There are lots of ways to solve this (shared state, passing references during initialization, setting delegate properties, broadcasting notifications, ...) but choosing one is part of choosing how you want to architect your app and there's no single answer for that, particularly while you're still learning these concepts.